# Calculating Euler's number

Tags: python, decimal

I'm writing some code to generate digits of the mathematical constant e (Eulers number), to any amount of precision.

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
import decimal

s = 300_000
n = Decimal(1)
x = Decimal(1)

print("[+] Summing numbers...")
getcontext().prec = s

for i in range(s, 1, -1):
    x *= i
    n += x

result = (n / x) + Decimal(1.0)
```

it works with 200k iterations or less, but fails if I set the precision higher then that.

```
[+] Summing numbers...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\OneDrive\Desktop\PYTHON\py\trig\log\calc e\e1_2.py", line 12, in <module>
    x *= i
decimal.Overflow: [<class 'decimal.Overflow'>]
>>>
```

How can I store very large numbers with python, that are hundreds of thousands of digits long, without throwing a decimal.Overflow error?

Comment: Use a string. Hundreds of thousands of sigfigs isn't useful for calculations because beyond a point it doesn't matter https://www.sciencefriday.com/segments/how-many-digits-of-pi-do-we-really-need

Comment: You need to set the `Emax` field in the context, not just `prec`.

Comment: @jasonharper I added the line `getcontext().Emax = s` on line 11, still seems to throw the same error though

Comment: Why do you use ``decimal`` in the first place? Those are *integer* operations. If you are worried about the precision of ``result``, performing this single operation via ``fraction`` is much more appropriate than ``decimal``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi They said they want *"hundreds of thousands of **digits**"*. Which `decimal` seems good for and `fraction` doesn't.

Comment: @nocomment `decimal` is totally unsuited for summing up *integers*. Most of their algorithm involves neither fractions nor (decimal) digits. Wanting a specific number of decimal digits *in the output* doesn’t mean that is suitable for the computation.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi How is it unsuited for summing up integers? It can do that just fine. And computing a `Decimal` is good for getting decimal output because then you don't need a conversion to an incompatible base. And how do you output hundreds of thousands of digits with `fraction` at all? You only showed how to get 16.

Comment: @nocomment I'm somewhat unhappy with the duplicate closure given your recent comments. It looks like specifically *formatting* of such numbers is not commonly covered by either questions or answers, and this one is vague enough to be suitable with minor edits. FWIW, the approach in your deleted answer could also well fit into this (perhaps better if it showed the same algorithm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `decimal` module exists for *decimal calculations*. For calculations with arbitrary precision numbers, use `int` and [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html).

```
from fractions import Fraction
s = 300_000
x = 1
n = 1

for i in range(s, 1, -1):
    x *= i
    n += x

result = Fraction(n, x) + 1
```

To specifically *display* the result with a given number of decimal digits, one can then [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.__format__) the result as desired:

```
# Display approximate value (the raw value is huge)
print(float(result))  # 2.718281828459045
# Display value with a given number of decimal digits
print(format(result, '.64g')) # 2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277
```

Note that since Python 3.11, there is [a limit on the digits that can be used in formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#integer-string-conversion-length-limitation) which also applies here. Use [`sys.set_int_max_str_digits`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.set_int_max_str_digits) to increase the limit (a value of `0` disables the limit).

Comment: this is really good thanks, how would I convert the result to a string to store in a text file. `with open("file.txt", "w") as file: file.write(str(result))` writes a strange number `140271359018057029500070152531295706311281685896...` etc.

Comment: How would you output their desired "hundreds of thousands of digits"? You only showed how to get 16.

Comment: @nocomment I've added an example of displaying 64 decimal digits. There's no problem to run `format(result, '.300000g')` if one desires.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that formatting yet. Was added only recently, in Python 3.12. Will try to test more later, right now I can only test up to s=100_000, where your way seems about 1.5 times slower than the question's.

Comment: Same speed ratio for s=300_000.

Comment: @nocomment Are you referring to the loop or the formatting?

Comment: [The whole thing (from start to string).](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rZO_bqQwEMaL6_wU08VcWAJXRSdtcVI23aZOZ1msTSwtBnlmJVane5I02yQPlafJgA3kT3suLDwz33w_G_v5tT_TU-cvl5cT2c3t24_Chq6Fg6ldq4_g2r4LBHdxmUNjqO48mYFESqVKMcls0DW5zuMsvE-BmCbXmjkzfs898IxC8FSgIeU8qVYPCimog2scoSwzsRrLrNhxHrazdbH_86h2PAlxMBa6wCKvjxKz3wJ4eC5NG5BVNoWG76FPBn0wNZfglLFdAAfOQ9C-MRJzqHLYVKl7bPdzC25ZerjewjAtg6FT8MB7kdLDDQwZXK_ORZllEXrvkEzYu7Nu3AI-UlbLFqr_AIOnI3Gr-a9In0ei6iMsW7SaZKzOwV4Vf_Ffc8Wk9uRrZP18xPknbiHM0Jt6NHjovBEjqlpRfyXGMWzH8NRt5aaSheOtkNkSW4itrEpVluWa6gNfFBnrYcNqJi2U8ro1Sq1lzkKicjhhrYbjWIij05IzR_xSqRENX9WZaJuk8dmk1zO_onc).

Comment: @nocomment Ah yes, I get similar timing differences for the loop as well. For decimal versus mine I get 18.2 s versus 22.9 s in the loop and 65.3 ms versus 7.75 s for the `result = ...` part. I'm guessing this is because the `n` and `x` computed in both methods *are not equal* as the precision set for Decimal is way too little to hold the results (about 973350 digits for s=200_000), so the Decimal variant keeps track of way less information (2x84320 bytes versus 2x431144 bytes for s=200_000); garbage collection for such huge blocks of memory is slow.

Comment: Note you can also do 300_000, the `getcontext().Emax = decimal.MAX_EMAX` makes that possible. (And btw yes, I agree that the duplicate target isn't right... This question is about sufficient Emax while the other one is about optimal prec.)

Comment: You can also do `getcontext().prec = decimal.MAX_PREC` before the loop and `getcontext().prec = s` after the loop, then I think it does as much work as yours and still seems slightly faster.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is in order of computation. Look at your summation loop:

```py
for i in range(300000, 1, -1):
    x *= i
    n += x
```

This computes `300000!` (factorial) -- that's your overflow problem.  You've exceeded the maximum value of the decimal package.

You need to investigate successive approximations to the values you need, rather than trying to divide two huge quantities.

Alternately, you can switch to Python **big integers**.  This will be very slow, but you'll get your result.

Comment: Calculating the numerator `x` and the denominator `n`, then dividing them only once at the end, seems to be one of the fastest methods I have come across for calculating high precision (it’s so fast I can calculate about 100k digits in 8 seconds). because computers are very good at adding/multiplying integers and can do addition quickly, but struggle with division. Where as dividing the numbers inside of the for loop on each iteration is extremely slow taking several mins. in terms of speed i think my current approach is the best one I found so far, i just need to find a way to store the ints.

Comment: Your current approach throws an exception before producing the desired result.  If the program only needs to throw an exception, I can make it a *lot* faster.  :-)

Comment: You simply need to handle the exception by switching methods; either check the iteration value before you start, or switch upon getting the exception.